# Trying to make a button that apears after achieving a certain score

Tags: xcode, swift, uibutton, xcode7

Im making a Single View Application in Swift and I want to create a button that appears on the screen once you get a certain score. How can I do this?

Also, if possible, I want the button to disappear after you click it.

Comment: how to you get and increase your score?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution by which i solved it is timer ...

```
var score : Int = 0
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  btnTest.hidden = true
  _ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector:Selector("printer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func printer() {
  score++
  if score == 10 {
    btnTest.hidden = false
  }
 }
```

you can set your updation on score variable.

there is also some other ways to do it

hope you found your solution

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. This site isn't a good fit for "teach me the basics of programming" type questions like this.

I'll give you something to start from though. Created a `score` property in your view controller. Implement a `didSet` method on your score property. Put the logic to show your button in your `didSet` method.

Answer (score 0):

Create a button and in your code hide it in viewDidLoad then reveal it whenever your score reaches the amount you wish. But it is correct that you should be providing code and not asking just how to do something. Stack overflow is for debugging errors not asking how code should be written.